# MySQL left join limit to one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database structure

```
table_countries
----------
country_id
country_name

table_cities
----------
city_id
country_id
city_name

table_streets
----------
street_id
city_id
street_name

table_people
----------
person_id
street_id
person_name
```

There multiple countries, which can have multiple cities, which in turn multiple streets and so on.

I am looking to perform a query that will get a list of all countries that have 1 or more people in them.

The problem is countries table is not linked directly to people table. And LEFT JOIN returns multiple rows for the same country.

Comment: It would probably depends on what you want to do in case there are multiple rows and you want to display one -- do you want to display the row from table2 with the minimum value of a given column, maximum, etc. ... without knowing more about the problem it'd be hard to say

Comment: please see my edit with more details

Comment: post `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` for each table, and some sample data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the expected result mentioned in your edit I would change the left joins to inner joins and select only country name with a group by clause. Note the foreign key names in the on clauses, I think you have to clarify/correct your table structures:

```
SELECT 
    table1.country

FROM
   table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
   JOIN table3 ON table2.id = table3.table2_id
   JOIN table4 ON table3.id = table4.table3_id

GROUP BY
    table1.country
```

Comment: this seems to be working - thank you all who answered :)

Comment: small correction: according to the last edit by the OP, there seem to be correct foreign keys. Important lesson here: (INNER) JOIN is often better suited (and faster) than LEFT JOIN... I sometimes need to remind myself...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (
SELECT DISTINCT table1.id
  FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN table2
         ON table1.id = table2.id
  LEFT JOIN table3
         ON table2.id = table3.id
  LEFT JOIN table4
         ON table3.id = table4.id
);
```

ought to do the trick then? You don't even need `DISTINCT`, but it will make the inner query sufficient if you just want to get the country IDs.

Comment: This will only give him data for table1.  He needs data from all the tables.

Comment: Sure, but it's unclear to me whether he really needs data from all the tables. The reason he did the join is that he wants to filter the countries to only show those that have people -- it was unclear to me as well until the edit.

Comment: @ethan: after his edit one requirement was to list all countries. No need to select other columns.

Answer (score 2):

You're problem goes beyond returning duplicate countries.  Basically, with any resource in your list, there's the possibility of duplication.  For example, if you have two roads for the city "Los Angeles", than "Los Angeles" will appear twice under the same country.

To solve this problem you can either, 1) have a separate query for each resource you want to return (bad idea), or 2) just handle the duplicate rows in your code that outputs the categories.

Like so:

```
$categories = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    if (!isset($categories[$row->country])) {
        $categories[$row->country] = array(
            'name' => $row->countryName,
            'cities' => array(),
        );        
    }
    if (!isset($categories[$row->country]['cities'][$row->city])) {
        $categories[$row->country]['cities'][$row->city] = array(
            'name' => $row->cityName,
            'roads' => array();
        );  
    }

    // ... and so on, with roads and people
}
```

The above will populate an array of people grouped by road, road group by city, and city group by country; which you can use to output your data in any way you wish.  Of course you could also modify the above code, to output your data immediately, instead of storing it in an array first.

Also, if you only want to return countries that have people, I would do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
   LEFT JOIN table2
             ON table1.id = table2.id
   LEFT JOIN table3
             ON table2.id = table3.id
   LEFT JOIN table4
             ON table3.id = table4.id
   WHERE table4.id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

2)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE id IN (
              SELECT id 
                FROM table4)
```

1) Not possible